# What information is stored by iOS Spell Checker?

Tags: ios, security, uitextview, spell-checking

I have heard that Apple's spell checker for UITextView maintains some kind of logging of what you type in individual applications.  I have a secure application where spell checking is a useful feature, however I don't want new words logged to somewhere outside of my application.  Can anyone refer me to an Apple reference document or technical description of what information is captured by spell check, and where it is captured too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know definitively, but using [fseventer](http://fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software%3afseventer%3astart), learning the word "aple" in TextEdit saves that word to `~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary`. Ignoring a word seems not to modify the filesystem at all, and indeed, if the document is closed and not saved, and a new document with that previously-ignored word is opened, it is no longer ignored. This is consistent with `+learnWord:` being a class method, and `-ignoreWord:` being an instance method. So for security, you could probably just never call `+learnWord:`, and instead have your own backend to persistently/securely store a list of ignored words.

Comment: Interesting... does guessesForWordRange:inString:language: or completionsForPartialWordRange:inString:language:
 have any FS Activity?  If not, then it should be possible to write my own UITextView subclass that spell checks without learning. (my actual goal)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this helps much, but you could do spell checking manually with the UITextChecker class which allows setting a list of ignored words:

```
- (void)setIgnoredWords:(NSArray *)words
```

More here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextChecker_Class/Reference/Reference.html

You can also check whether the word has been learned with:

```
+ (BOOL)hasLearnedWord:(NSString *)word
```

Comment: Bit related here, but would it be possible to automatically accept all misspelled words using UITextChecker?

Comment: I see but say a certain word In a UITextField is misspelled for example instead of "apple" it said "aple". If I call learnWord(NSSString*) will that automatically change it to "apple"?

Comment: Good Info, but the question was more framed on where the information that apple captures is stored, and when it is stored.

Comment: you could keep track of all the words you learn, and unlearn them when the app quits, and re-learn them when the app opens.